# Checking for broken links

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hyperlinks

Is there a way to automaticaly check posts on the main site for broken links?

Do you think it be worth doing?

If we discover a broken link what should we do about it?

Answer (score 2):

I think if you see broken links, you should try to fix them.

However, this is also why we have a policy that **posts should *always* have enough context that they are still complete answers even if the link goes dark** -- and that's the really important part.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer

> ### Provide context for links
>
> A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there . Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

If an answer is useless with a dead link, it means the answer *is incomplete!*

Comment: Does this still hold true for links within SE? Without being dupes, some answers refer to other questions, and I'm guessing we don't want to overdo duplication within SE. What's the best policy here?

Comment: @Rory, links within SE very rarely "go dark" because it's rare to fully remove a post. That said, people sometimes delete their own answers to a question, so it's probably still better to say "as it says here[1], you should…" instead of "read this answer[1]."

Comment: Though I most certainly agree answers that just point to other sites are not real answers, I think it would be great (if it's possible and practical) to have something in the "moderator tools" that helps check for broken links.